# how to query data based on datetime from dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Table: Customer
Hashkey: email
Other Attributes: name, address, purchasedamount, datecreated
**Sample Data:**

1. "xxx1.xxx.com", "XXXXX1", "no1.street",2500,"10-01-2017 01:02:03"
2. "xxx2.xxx.com", "XXXXX2", "no2.street",2000,"11-01-2017 04:05:06"
3. "xxx3.xxx.com", "XXXXX3", "no3.street",4050,"10-02-2017 07:08:09"
4. "xxx4.xxx.com", "XXXXX4", "no4.street",2800,"11-02-2017 10:11:12"

How to fetch customers, whose purchased date from "11-01-2017 00:00:00" to "10-02-2017 00:00:00".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample data, I don't see an easy way to do it unfortunately. I would say you need to do it in code (Scan all items and filter at the application level).

If changing the data model is an option:

Easiest and recommended approach with date / times in DynamoDB is to store is in ISO8601 format, using String data type.

ISO8601: Date and time values are ordered from the largest to smallest unit of time: year, month (or week), day, hour, minute, second, and fraction of second. The lexicographical order of the representation thus corresponds to chronological order, except for date representations involving negative years. This allows dates to be naturally sorted by, for example, DynamoDB.

If you use your Date attribute as a Sort Key / [LSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html), it enables you to ask DynamoDB to do the heavy lifting for querying between two dates (within a Partition Key), by using the BETWEEN comparison operator.

Comment: 4 option 1: ISO8601 format data type String or Number,  which one best?  there any possibility to add LSIfor existing table.

Comment: If using Epoch Time (this is also how TTL feature works), then use Number. If using ISO8601 format, use String. Unfortunately creating an LSI isn't possible on an existing table, it is a table creation activity only. Although creating a GSI is possible. You can use triggers to migrate to a new table with the LSI using the steps found here: https://www.abhayachauhan.com/?p=136.